# Как отобразить на MapView обькты сохранённые в CoreDate

Tags: swiftui, mapview

У меня база данных точек в CoreDate с координатами и названиями. Как мне их отобразить на карте. Зареве спасибо за ответ

```
            Map(
            coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion,
            annotationItems: fetchedList
        ) { location in
            MapAnnotation(
                coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                    latitude: location.lat,
                    longitude: location.long
                )
            ) {
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "grid.circle")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        .shadow(radius: 1)
                    Text(location.name ?? "")
                        .font(.caption2)
                        .bold()
                }
            }
        }
```

Это код отображает только с одного Entity, но мне надо с двух разных Entity

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: Map(
            coordinateRegion: $coordinateRegion,
            annotationItems: fetchedList
        ) { location in

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и добавьте полный пример туда

Comment: готово добавил код

Comment: я как понимаю точки из одного Entity содержаться в массиве fetchedList, почему бы не добавить точки из второго Entity в этот массив?